# Rewriting a plot expression to add an option works, but with an unexpected error message

Tags: plotting, replacement

I'm trying to rewrite a `ListDensityPlot` expression to systematiccaly add an option:

```
SetAttributes[myShow, HoldAll]
myShow[plots__] := With[{
   mplots = Hold[{plots}] /. {
      ListDensityPlot[args__] :> 
       ListDensityPlot[args, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
      }
   }, Show[
   Sequence[ReleaseHold[mplots]]
   ]
  ]

myShow[
 ListDensityPlot[({#1, #2, #1*#2}) & @@@ Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]]
 ]
```

It looks like it works since the plot is using the ColorFunction specified in my replacement rule. However, alongside the graphic, I also have the error message:

> ```
> ListDensityPlot::arrayerr -- args__ must be a valid array.
> ```

[image]

Could you explain what is causing this error message and how to fix that?

Comment: Replace   `ListDensityPlot[args__] :> ...` with `HoldPattern[ListDensityPlot[args__]] :> ...`? (`ListDensityPlot` does not have the  `Hold` attribute. So we need to prevent  `ListDensityPlot[args__]` from being evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, @kglr. I spend more than one-hour trying different things before asking the question. And I found `HoldPattern` just after having posted here! I took the liberty to self answer my question below. I tried to explain what was happening to the best of my Mathematica skills. Don't hesitate to correct me if necessary.

Comment: Interesting @kglr. I will try that immediately. Do you know if there is any rationale explaining why different plot functions have different `Hold*` attributes?

Comment: Sylvain, I misspoke re the real reason for the need to wrap the rhs with `HoldPattern` (as you explain in your answer it is the fact that `RuleDelayed` does not have the  `HoldAll` attribute).

Answer (score 4):

[`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) is the solution.

For some reason, I thought both sides of a delayed expression remained unevaluated. However:

```
Attributes[RuleDelayed]
```

> ```
> {HoldRest,Protected,SequenceHold}
> ```

As you can see, [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) has the attribute [`HoldRest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) and not [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html). So, I was wrong: the left-hand side of a delayed rule *is* evaluated.

So, in my case, Mathematica tried to evaluate `ListDensityPlot[args__]` -- which produced an error and returned the expression unevaluated. Then, this unevaluated expression was used as the left-hand side for the replacement rule. Making it work "as expected".

To prevent evaluation of the left-hand side, we must use `HoldPattern`:

```
 mplots = Hold[{plots}] /. {
      HoldPattern[ListDensityPlot[args__]] :> 
       ListDensityPlot[args, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
      }
   }
```